# Is there anything SE Inc can do to support all the new online learners?

Tags: discussion

Given the new mandated shifts to online learning during the outbreak, I find myself worrying about those students who manage to scrape by in a traditional learning environment with study groups and the help of their peers, let alone the help of university tutoring resources.

The people that are involved in tutoring resources are probably way too busy right now to keep that going with anywhere near the efficacy they did in the before time.  Other than really constraining discussion forums inherent to our LMS's, collaborative tools are sparse.

Given that so many industries, like carriers, publishers, content providers, are bending over backwards to support education (including higher education), I'm wondering if any of the SE products can help with alleviating the lack of student-student interactions.

In the long run, this might open some new markets to SE, and might prove a boon.  In the short run, our students need help to make the second half of this semester a better learning experience, and if SE can make the right tools available, that's a good thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stack Overflow Needs Mentors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111397/282094), https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118521/282094, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149151/282094, etc. - See "Linked" in the right column.

Comment: @rob Not particularly. There's a real difference between how the platform is meant to be used and whether there's additional utility that can be sucked out of it during a pandemic.  There are reasons for rules, and reasons to abandon them.

Comment: Scott, such a feature was available for testing and [wasn't popular](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=mentoring%20is%3aquestion). You have tagged your question for discussion not a feature request (implementation of your idea), the ability to discuss, suggest or request are incorporeal to the result.

Answer (score 6):

In times of crisis I think it is important to have access to tools that can be relied upon.

Stack Exchange sites are the "go to places" for instant answers to questions users may have been thinking about asking here or somewhere else.

I think we will be doing the community the greatest service if we can:

1. Maintain and improve our sites with Q&A that is at least as focused as it is today;
2. Help students to learn how to use these sites without downgrading the quality of their content.